# jQuery loading screen delay

Tags: jquery, loading, preloader

I am using the script below, for my loading screen.
If you can notice, it hides the loading screen before the website has finished loading.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function hide_preloader() { rotate = 0; $(".preloader").fadeOut(250); });
```

Is there something I can do to fix this, that I am obviously overlooking?

**[Live preview here](https://secure.saoi.org/donate/464681/)**

Thanks

Comment: `$(window).load()` instead of `$(document).ready()`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the problem is. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Jean-Do Open the link in your browser. You'll notice the loading screen, fades out, with some of the images and custom font not loaded.

Comment: Got it. So OneOfOne got it right, $(window).load would do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.ready` fires when the dom is ready (= all elements got parsed), it doesn't mean all resources/images got loaded.

what you need is to use :

```
$(window).load(function() {
  // Run code
   rotate = 0;
    $(".preloader").fadeOut(250);
});
```